# BigInteger.valueOf() for very big numbers?

Tags: java, parsing, biginteger

What would be the best way to convert a 50-digit String to a BigInteger in Java? It doesn't have a valueOf(String) method, and I can't convert to Long because it's too small.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does have a [`BigInteger(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)) constructor :-)

```
String S = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(S);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(my50DigitString);
```

All those Xxx.valueOf() methods are alternatives to constructors because they allow for returning shared, cached copies.  Constructors, by definition, return a new instance every time.  So valueOf() are a nice optimization, but the designers apparently didn't find it interesting to provide a BigInteger.valueOf(String) method.  You'll have to use a one of the constructors in this case.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger has a constructor that takes a String.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger(s);
```