# How to convert an integer to bigdecimal in Java

Tags: java, integer, bigdecimal

I want to create a method that calculates multiplication of an integer and a bigdecimal. I search on Google and forums, but I didn't find anything.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
private Integer quantite;
private BigDecimal prixUnit;

public Integer getQuantite() {
        return quantite;
}

public void setQuantite(Integer quantite) {
    this.quantite = quantite;
}


public BigDecimal getPrixUnit() {
    return prixUnit;
}

public void setPrixUnit(BigDecimal prixUnit) {
    this.prixUnit = prixUnit;
}

public BigDecimal methCal(BigDecimal quantite, BigDecimal prixUnit) {

    this.prixUnit=prixUnit;
    BigDecimal j = new BigDecimal(quantite);
    this.j = quantite;

    return quantite*prixUnit;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please show your current code, your attempt and explain in more detail the input + expected output.

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf(13)`.

Comment: [`BigDecimal.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf-long-) ... the documentation is the first step.

Comment: I @luk2302 add the code

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To multiply an integer (or byte/short/float/double) with a BigInteger (or BigDecimal), you must convert the native number to BigInteger/BigDecimal first.

```
// int parameter can be int or Integer
public static BigInteger multiply ( int a, BigInteger b ) {
   return BigInteger.valueOf( a ).multiply( b );
}

// BigInteger <> BigDecimal
public static BigDecimal multiply ( int a, BigDecimal b ) {
   return BigDecimal.valueOf( a ).multiply( b );
}

// same for add, subtract, divide, mod etc.
```

> Note: `valueOf` is not the same as `new`, and for different reasons on [BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186204/bigdecimal-to-use-new-or-valueof) and [BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344007/893578).
>   In both cases, I recommend `valueOf` over `new`.

---

I see that you added your code, nice.
It doesn't work because Integer is mixed with BigDecimal, and also `*` does not work with BigDecimal.
If you compare it with my code, the fix should be obvious:

```
public BigDecimal methCal ( int quantite, BigDecimal prixUnit ) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf( quantite ).multiply( prixUnit );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Google definitely could have helped you, if you know what to look for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-int-

This is one of the constructors for BigDecimal, which allows you to do the following:

```
BigDecimal five = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
BigDecimal seven = BigDecimal.valueOf(2).add(five);
```

Seeing as you stated you wanted to multiply an int and a BigDecimal, this would be achieved as follows:

```
BigDecimal result = yourBigDecimal.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(yourInt));
```

And, supposing you want this result as an int:

```
int intResult = result.intValue();
```

Keep in mind that this throws away the fraction though. If you want rounding instead:

```
int intResult = result.round(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).intValue();
```

Comment: For a general purpose (floating-point values), I suggest you take a look at [Sheepy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49853691/4391450). `valueOf` is more efficient for floating-point value. it is a better approach.

Comment: @AxelH neither the question nor my answer deals with floating points as input though, and the closest relevant equivalent takes a long as parameter. That said, `valueOf` appears to yield cached values for values 0-10, which is more efficient than creating a new BigDecimal each time, so valueOf is indeed a better option.

Comment: I said, for general purpose. It wasn't against your answer but to give more information in case of a floating point usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.math.*;

public class calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("3383878445");
        BigDecimal returnValue = calculation(2, value1);
        System.out.println("value is:" + returnValue);
    }

    public static BigDecimal calculation(int no1, BigDecimal no2) {
        BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.valueOf(no1).multiply(no2);
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods from the Java API will be helpful.

```
public BigDecimal multiply​(BigDecimal multiplicand)
```

Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this × multiplicand), and whose scale is (this.scale() + multiplicand.scale()).

Parameters:
multiplicand - value to be multiplied by this BigDecimal.
Returns:
this * multiplicand

```
public BigDecimal​(int val)
```

Translates an int into a BigDecimal. The scale of the BigDecimal is zero.

Parameters:
val - int value to be converted to BigDecimal.