# Using Java Streams to process a list with multiple fields that impact the result

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Java 8 here. I have the following POJO:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class Orderline {
    private Integer qty;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String productName; 
}
```

I'm looking for a Stream-y way of iterating through a `List<Orderlines>` and coming up with a `subtotal` based on their individual quantities and prices. The "old" (pre-Stream) way of doing this would look like:

```java
List<Orderline> orderlines = order.getOrderlines();
double sub = 0.0;
for (Orderline ol : orderlines) {
    sub += ol.getQty() * ol.getPrice();
}

BigDecimal subtotal = BigDecimal.valueOf(sub);
```

My best attempt at using Streams to accomplish this is:

```java
BigDecimal subtotal = order.getOrderlines().stream()
    .map(Orderline::getPrice)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

However this doesn't take their quantities into consideration. **Any ideas how I can accomplish this?**

Comment: Can you add an `amount()` method to the POJO which calculates this value and then use `.reduce` on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
map(x->x.getPrice().multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(x.getQty())))
```

in your second line.

Comment: Thanks @g_bor (+1) but this adds a compiler error: "`Operator '*' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Integer', 'java.math.BigDecimal`"

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Then simply replace `x.getPrice() * x.getQty()` with `x.getQty.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(x.getPrice()))`.

Comment: This is an independent error. It says you can't simply * an Integer and a Bigdecimal. This should cause an error in the old approach also.

Comment: @g_bor You could, however, edit your post so this problem is fixed.

Comment: Thanks for taking care. I believe it is correct now.

Comment: Thanks guys, but `qty` is an `Integer` field and there is no `multiple(...)` method on it. The `price` is the `BigDecimal`. The posted solution still does not work!

Comment: You are right, and the type was not correct either... Sorry.

Comment: This thread answers that part of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853552/how-to-convert-integer-to-bigdecimal-in-java